# How to tell a C++ program to get the system memory?

Tags: c++, linux, memory-management

I am writing a quantum chemistry program and in the course of its development, I come to a point where I have to decide between memory consumption and execution time. To put it briefly, if I choose the execution time, the run can become significantly faster because some big matrices need be computed once and stored in memory for later purposes. If I chose to preserve the memory, these matrices will be calculated at each iteration and the execution time increases quickly. Now I want to make my program to automatically detect how much memory my system has and use that information to automatically decide whether to preserve memory or chose a faster execution. I want something that goes in the line where I specify a fraction of the total memory that my program is allowed to use. How to achieve this using C++?

The program runs on a computer cluster and the minimum memory per core it has is 32 GB. Is there some kind of suggested memory consumption good programs usually have? I have access to a similar program and the output of a certain run is the following,

```
       Memory information
       ------------------

heap     =   13107198 doubles =    100.0 Mbytes
stack    =   13107195 doubles =    100.0 Mbytes
global   =   26214400 doubles =    200.0 Mbytes (distinct from heap & stack)
total    =   52428793 doubles =    400.0 Mbytes
verify   = yes
hardfail = no
```

I am wondering why it has division of memory usage into heap, stack, and global. Does it mean that I can actually specify in my program which part of memory certain data are to be stored?

Comment: Standard `c++` does not have this ability. You likely have to use an OS API.

Comment: @NateEldredge I took a look at that question, while it looks pretty relevant, there are many new terms that makes me wonder if it is really close to what I want to achieve.

Comment: @drescherjm I have never used an API before, how to use it and is it downloadable?

Comment: My point was it may depend on what operating system you are using windows, linux, macOS, bsd ...

Comment: I am using linux.